# How can I configure Postfix to retain copies of all email sent through it?

Tags: postfix

My company currently uses Google Apps for email.  I can configure Google Apps to forward all outgoing email through a relay server.  I can also point my MX records at this server and have it forward incoming mail onto Google.  Therefore I can configure Postfix act as a proxy for all email that is both sent to and from our users.  This part is done and works fine.  However, I'm not sure how to retain a full copy of each message that passes through it.

I'm interested in doing this so that all email to/from customers can be dumped into our CRM system so they're searchable by everyone in our company who might talk to a customer.  The most common way of doing this is to have a "always BCC" setting specified in Postfix.  However, this would only archive email sent to customers, not email received from them.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: If all submitted mail passes through ppostfix, and all received mail is forwarded to postfix, WHY are you using Google Apps, again ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're mistaken - all mail is received, all mail is delivered.

As documented, always_bcc defines an address where copies of **all** mail handled by postfix are sent to.

Everything.

For better control over this process, use sender_bcc_maps and recipient_bcc_maps; some judicious use of regex maps allows you to copy the messages to the same user on an archive domain - for both senders and recipients, like so:

```
sender_bcc_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/archive_domain
recipient_bcc_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/archive_domain
```

In `/etc/postfix/archive_domain`:

```
/^([^@]+)\@example\.com$/    $1@archive.example.com
```

You can now handle mail to @archive.example.com however you please.