# How to BCC copy all outgoing emails with Postfix?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server, ubuntu-14.04

I have a VPS on DigitalOcean where I have installed Postfix. I'd like to add in BCC an email address of my choice for all the emails that passing through Postfix go to email addresses not in my system. The email addresses in use in my VPS are stored in a MySQL table and [this is the guide I used to set everything up](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin).

I've read a lot of articles on this subject but none of them explains how to achieve my goal. Specifically, all the tutorials I've read (such as [1](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/postfix-copy-all-outgoing-mail-to-admin-account-583868/), [2](https://www.aptgetlife.co.uk/auditing-postfix-adding-sender-bcc-to-monitor-outgoing-email/), [3](https://serverfault.com/questions/407302/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-retain-copies-of-all-email-sent-through-it), and [4](http://www.sudosu.in/2013/06/create-bcc-of-incoming-and-outgoing_26.html)) suggest the use of `always_bcc`, `sender_bcc_maps`, or `recipient_bcc_maps`. These options are not helpful because they BCC all the emails coming from outside of the server.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You have to write a milter, no other way as far as i know.

Comment: @Tutul Hi. Thank you for the comment. Can you be a bit more explicit or give me a guide or link to do that? I'm not an expert, so I don't know what that means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure Postfix to retain copies of all email sent through it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/407302/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-retain-copies-of-all-email-sent-through-it)