# how to copy all emails send to external email account(postfix)

Tags: postfix

The company at which i work, requested to copy all emails sent to a specific external email address(bcc those emails to an internal monitoring email account). They specifically asked for one recipient account, and not for all the outgoing emails. Is it possible to implement this in postfix?

The postfix server uses virtual users (set up in a plain text file, not mysql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure Postfix to retain copies of all email sent through it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/407302/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-retain-copies-of-all-email-sent-through-it)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Not really. I want to bcc a specific recipient to a specific monitoring address.

Comment: That is explained in the accepted answer of the linked question

Comment: @GeraldSchneider unfortunately the mentioned solution does not work for external email recipients.

Comment: If you found a working configuration, please post it as an answer and accept it when you are allowed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following configuration works:
Add to main.cf:

```
# shadow bcc
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/shadow_sender
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/shadow_sender
```

add to the shadow_sender file:

```
recipient@server.com monitoring@internal.com
```

then run

```
postmap /etc/postfix/shadow_sender
/etc/init.d/posfix reload
```